# JSON Deserializing for iOS

Tags: ios, django, json, serialization, deserialization

I am trying to deserialize a JSON string for an iOS app that I am writing. However, my app keeps getting hung up on the "\" escape sequence for double-quotes in the feed I am trying to read. What is a quick way to strip out that sequence so I can parse the feed correctly? (The feed is coming from my Django application on the server-side.)

Here is my json string:

```
[{\"pk\": 4161, \"model\": \"news.article\", \"fields\": {\"date_live\": \"2011-11-03 00:00:01\", \"date_added\": \"2011-11-03 03:10:59\", \"date_modified\": \"2011-11-03 03:10:59\", \"slug\": \"thursday-feature-backup-comic\", \"title\": \"THURSDAY FEATURE --> Backup Comic\"}}
```

You will notice that all of my "nodes" have the "\" escape sequence for the quote. Any ideas?

Thank you in advance for any help here.

L.

Comment: How are you producing that feed?

Comment: Is that what the output actually looks like? Or is that a string literal? if it's a string literal, then the '\' characters aren't actually there.  You're just seeing them when the string gets printed to the console.  If they are there, then your JSON string is malformed.
Also are you using something like [JSONkit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit) or just parsing the JSON yourself?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I am producing the feed using Python / Django. I run a query and use simplejson to format the output as a JSON string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to remove the escape inside python:

```
import re, json
myjson = re.sub(r"\\", "", "[{\"pk\": 4161, \"model\": \"news.article\", \"fields\": {\"date_live\": \"2011-11-03 00:00:01\", \"date_added\": \"2011-11-03 03:10:59\", \"date_modified\": \"2011-11-03 03:10:59\", \"slug\": \"thursday-feature-backup-comic\", \"title\": \"THURSDAY FEATURE --> Backup Comic\"}}]")
myjson = json.loads(myjson) # will decode json
```

But if you want to remove the escape from javascript:

```
myjson = "[{\"pk\": 4161, \"model\": \"news.article\", \"fields\": {\"date_live\": \"2011-11-03 00:00:01\", \"date_added\": \"2011-11-03 03:10:59\", \"date_modified\": \"2011-11-03 03:10:59\", \"slug\": \"thursday-feature-backup-comic\", \"title\": \"THURSDAY FEATURE --> Backup Comic\"}}]";
myjson = eval(myjson.replace(/\\/, "")); // will encode json
```

**Note:** You forgot a ] at the end of your string. At least I had an error when I've tryed to eval it. I put the ] at the end and eval worked.

Comment: Thanks Guilherme! I figured out what the problem is. My json parser on the iPhone is choking on the "node" after the first one in my string. I have to fix that. This was a very helpful answer.